# .htaccess How to change the order of GET parametrs in URL?

Tags: .htaccess

Google sees the following URLs differently:

**/united-arab-emirates-civil-engineer-jobs-vacancy.html?ct=p&wp=p&city=ras%20al-khaimah**

**/united-arab-emirates-civil-engineer-jobs-vacancy.html?wp=p&ct=p&city=ras%20al-khaimah**

I need to find the way to change the order to only one correct way by using `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not easy to do with htaccess.

I think the best way to do that is to add the html header in your page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/united-arab-emirates-civil-engineer-jobs-vacancy.html?ct=p&wp=p&city=ras%20al-khaimah"/>
```

However, you must adjust the parameter values with the script language you use in your pages (eg PHP).

You can read: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066